# Does Anything Exixts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I Mean that Does Anything In The Universe Exists By Means Of Quantum Mechanics...I Heard This From Someone But i wanna be sure that it is really true or what?.

Comment: This does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to our current theories, not only does something exist, but many things do. To get a grasp on a more quantitative understanding on the numbers we are talking about, you can check vSauce's video on ["How many things are there?"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6eOcd06kdk) and the links in the description, as well as some comments.